# CMake - Cannot find the generated header files

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I have the following folder structure:

```
root
│ └── CMakeLists.txt
|── protos
│ ├── myproto.proto
│ └── CMakeLists.txt
├── client
│ ├── client.cpp
│ └── CMakeLists.txt
├── ...
```

I generated the c++ code corresponding to my `.proto` files, they were placed into the folder `build/bin`.  At the end the linking fails.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` code in the `proto` folder:

```
get_filename_component(my_proto "./myproto.proto" ABSOLUTE) #gives the total path and filename
get_filename_component(my_proto_path "${my_proto}" DIRECTORY) #gives the directory path

set(my_proto_srcs "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/myproto.pb.cc") 
set(my_proto_hdrs "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/myproto.pb.h")
set(my_grpc_srcs "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/myproto.grpc.pb.cc")
set(my_grpc_hdrs "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/myproto.grpc.pb.h")

add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT "${my_proto_srcs}" "${my_proto_hdrs}" "${my_grpc_srcs}" "${my_grpc_hdrs}"
     COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
     ARGS --grpc_out "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
          --cpp_out "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
          -I "${my_proto_path}"
          --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
          "${my_proto}"
     DEPENDS "${my_proto}")
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_library(my_grpc_proto
       ${my_grpc_srcs}
       ${my_grpc_hdrs}
       ${my_proto_srcs}
       ${my_proto_hdrs})

target_link_libraries(my_grpc_proto
       ${_REFLECTION}
       ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
       ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` of my `client` folder reads as:

```
add_executable(client client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(client
      my_grpc_proto
      ${_REFLECTION}
      ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
      ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
```

And in `client.cpp` i have

```
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "myproto.grpc.pb.h"
```

When I build it, I get the error message:

```
cmake --build .
[ 50%] Built target my_grpc_proto
[ 62%] Building CXX object client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.cpp.obj

C:\Users\code\gRPC\client\client.cpp:4:10: fatal error: myproto.grpc.pb.h: No such file or directory

  4 | #include "myproto.grpc.pb.h"

  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   compilation terminated.

mingw32-make[2]: *** [client\CMakeFiles\client.dir\build.make:76: client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:159: client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2 
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Command `include_directories`, called in `proto/CMakeLists.txt`, affects on the `my_grpc_proto` library which is created in the same CMake file, but doesn't affect on `client` executable, which is create in **other** CMake file (`client/CMakeLists.txt`). Instead `include_directories` you could use `target_include_directories(my_grpc_proto PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")`, so given include directory will be added not only to `my_grpc_proto` library, but also to anyone who links with that library.